# Fogbugz - I need a screen capture tool - terminal services compliant

Tags: screen-capture

Im looking for a tool that provides similar features to a tool called BugShooting, the gotcha is that it needs to work on Terminal Services, so far I have almost gone bald trying to get Bugshooting to reliably work within Terminal Services.

Does anyone have any good recomendations for a tool to replace bugshooting but with a similar set of features?

I was going to use the Fogbugz screen capture tool however its far too basic for what we want.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The FogBugz website lists a number of other screen capture tools that integrate with it [here](http://www.fogcreek.com/fogbugz/extras.html). I don't know if any of those tools match BugShooting's features or not though.

I personally use [TechSmith's SnagIt](http://www.techsmith.com/snagit.html) (which has [FogBugz integration](http://www.techsmith.com/snagit-accessories.html)) and generally works really well.

Comment: whilst most of the tools do not have the features of bugshooting, we settled with the standard fogbugz screen capture tool for the following reasons, its free, it works and its very simple to use :) turns out that most of the features in bugshooting were never used.